# How to get the memory size of an array of strings?

Tags: c, arrays, memory

I will try to explain with an example:

Let say I would like to create a message list with a fixed number, 3.

```
char* p_msglist[3];
```

Each message in this list should be stored in a fixed size (e.g. 16 chars, so each message holds 16 bytes in memory, 48 bytes total).

```
char msg[16] = "first message";
char msg2[16] = "second message";
char msg3[16] = "third message";
```

After pointing each of these messages in list, I printed `sizeof` the first message and the list:

```
p_msglist[0] = msg;
p_msglist[1] = msg2;
p_msglist[2] = msg3;
printf("%lu\n", sizeof(msg));
printf("%lu\n", sizeof(p_msglist));
```

**Output:**

```
16  //size of msg is ok. 
24
```

I know that a *char pointer* holds 8 bytes and our message list initialized with 3 elements, the last line prints out 24. I want to ask:

- Is there a way to get that my list holds `3*16=48` bytes. Trying to ask that: may I be sure that my list holds 48 bytes in memory?
- If I would like to allocate memory (`malloc` etc.), should I care for the pointer of the list and the list itself (24 bytes + 48 bytes)?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If the targets of the pointers stored in `p_msglist` are always going to be associated with `p_msglist` and are always going to be 16 bytes, you probably want a multidimensional array (`char p_msglist[3][16];`) not a pointer array. A pointer array doesn't care about what it pointers point or who manages that storage.

Comment: "I know that a char pointer holds 8 bytes"  No, a `char *` *may* be 8 bytes.  It's also very often 4 bytes.  Or it can be something else entirely.

Comment: Yes I know that also :) I meant that for my case it is 8 byte. But you are right I should have written that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a very basic misunderstanding there of how an array of pointers works. It holds *pointers* to memory, not the memory itself. (It cannot do that because, at the point you declared `p_msglist`, the size of the messages was not yet known.)

```
char* p_msglist[3];
```

This is an array of three pointers. Each of these pointers means an address. An address is usually (but not on every hardware) either 32 or 64 bit large; that is 4 or 8 bytes, respectively.

You are working on a 64bit machine, hence your array of three pointers is 3 x 8 = 24 bytes.

Now to the important point:

*Each of the three pointers can point to some different address.* There is neither necessity nor guarantee whatsoever that your three messages reside even close to each other in memory. The memory for the messages pointed to is **not** included in `sizeof p_msglist` -- nor should it, really.

If you want to `malloc` the memory for the whole `p_msglist` **and** the messages, you would have to:

- allocate 24 bytes for `p_msglist`; then
- allocate 16 bytes for each message, separately, *and store the address for that message in an element of `p_msglist`, respectively*.

When freeing the memory again, you would have to call `free()` on each message (i.e., `free( p_msglist[0] )`, `free( p_msglist[1] )`, `free( p_msglist[2] )`), *and* `free( p_msglist )` itself. (Important: First free the messages, *then* free the array. The other way around would be Undefined Behaviour.)

If you want to ensure that the messages are consecutive in memory, you would need to allocate 3 * 16 = 48 bytes for the messages (let's say you store it in `msg_mem`), and store `msg_mem` in `p_msglist[0]`, store `msg_mem + 16` in `p_msglist[1]`, and store `msg_mem + 32` in `p_msglist[2]`.

When freeing *that*, you *must not* call `free()` on the individual messages, only on `p_msglist[0]` (and `p_msglist`, if you allocated memory for that dynamically). You only ever call `free()` on the very same address you previously got from one of the allocation functions.

If you want to have the messages *and* `p_msglist` in consecutive and allocated memory, you  would have to allocate 48 + 24 = 72 bytes of memory (`sizeof( p_msglist ) + sizeof( msg ) + sizeof( msg2 ) + sizeof( msg3 )`)... and of course *only* `free( p_msglist )` afterwards.

---

If you do not want to `malloc` the memory *at all* and still want the memory to be in one block, you can declare...

```
char p_msglist[3][16] = { { "first message" }, { "second message" }, { "third message" } };
```

This would allocate a two-dimensional array of 3 x 16 characters, initializing them as indicated. This, however, would of course be a *local* object only, which goes out of scope as any other local variable would (as opposing to dynamically allocated memory, which remains valid until `free()`d).

The "funny" thing about that latter construct is, since `p_msglist` is a two-dimensional array "directly" instead of holding three pointers to *individual* arrays, `sizeof p_msglist` in this case is, actually, 3 x 16 =  48...

Comment: Thanks for such explanatory answer :)

Comment: @ErselEr: I distinctly remember the mental contortions I had to put myself through before I "got" pointers, back then in primordial times... I know how confusing it can be if you don't have somebody to set you on track and give you a little push. ;-)

Comment: Yeah, u are right. Thanks again :) Btw, I have just started to use stackoverflow in an active manner and I'm very appreciated thanks to you

Answer (score 2):

The answer to the first question is no. You can't get the size from the pointer itself.

That depends:-

1. If you want to allocate those `char*`'s then yes you need to consider.
2. If you are sure it is sufficient to have 3 `char*` then `no` you don't need to consider.

but in both case you need to allocated memory to store the character string. You will for example here allocate space for storing 16 characters.

(or simply assign it to some string literal).